# On IFTTT, the @-sign is cut from queued tweets in an RSS feed. How to resolve?

Tags: twitter, rss, ifttt

I've set up an IFTTT where an RSS feed is checked for new items. If new items exist, they are tweeted through a particular Twitter account.
This works well, except that references to other Twitter accounts, using the @-sign, are culled, in that the @-sign is removed.

So, if my queued tweet is this:

"A shoutout to @someone."

IFTTT actually publishes this:

"A shoutout to someone."

This is not desirable behaviour. How to make this work as intended?

Comment: This is because automated @mentions are against the [Twitter automation policy](https://help.twitter.com/en/rules-and-policies/twitter-automation), IFTTT knows this, and strips them out.

Comment: Indeed, thanks! Make it an answer and I accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because automated @mentions are against the Twitter automation policy, IFTTT knows this, and strips them out.